How to filter YML value and print output CSV file?
I am using below code to get device information as YML, need to filter the values of devices and print output to a CSV file.
  - name: get system log
    connection: local
    check_mode: no
    uri:
      validate_certs: no
      url: "https://{{ provider.ip_address }}/api/?type=op&cmd=<show><monitoring><health><device><all></all></device></health></monitoring></show>&key={{ auth.api_key }}"
      return_content: yes
      method: GET
    register: output

  - name: translate returned content from XML output into YML
    set_fact:
      YML: "{{ output['content'] | ansible.utils.from_xml }}"

  - name: Output-TO-FILE
    debug:
      msg: "{{ YML.response.result }}"

I have share the code I have used and output I need to filter from.
This output has information from 2 devices but the actual output may have multiple device information
"msg": {
"response": {
"@status": "success",
"result": {
"entry": [
{
"cps": "26",
"deviating_fields": {
"dp-cpu": null,
 "logging-rate": null
},
"device-id": "1",
"dp-cpu": "4",
"fan-total": "0",
"fan-up": "0",
"hostname": "FW1",
"logging-rate": "74",
"model": "PA-VM",
"mp-cpu": "12",
"mp-mem": "38",
"port-total": "7",
"port-up": "2",
"power-total": "0",
"power-up": "0",
"sessions": "3070",
"throughput": "42190"
},
 {
"cps": "44",
"deviating_fields": {
"logging-rate": null
},
"device-id": "2",
"dp-cpu": "2",
"fan-total": "0",
"fan-up": "0",
"hostname": "FW2",
"logging-rate": "64",
"model": "PA-VM",
"mp-cpu": "12",
"mp-mem": "38",
"port-total": "7",
"port-up": "2",
"power-total": "0",
"power-up": "0",
"sessions": "2836",
"throughput": "7195"
}

I am looking for the steps to filter the values like hostname, device-id, dp-cpu and print them to CSV file.
...
"device-id": "1",
"dp-cpu": "4",
...
"device-id": "2",
"dp-cpu": "2",


Given the mre simplified data
    YML:
      response:
        result:
          response:
            '@status': success
            result:
              entry:
              - cps: '26'
                deviating_fields:
                  dp-cpu: null
                  logging-rate: null
                device-id: '1'
                dp-cpu: '4'
                fan-total: '0'
                fan-up: '0'
                hostname: FW1
              - cps: '44'
                deviating_fields:
                  logging-rate: null
                device-id: '2'
                dp-cpu: '2'
                fan-total: '0'
                fan-up: '0'
                hostname: FW2


Q: "Filter the values like hostname, device-id, dp-cpu and print them to CSV file."
A: Declare the field-names
    fnames: [hostname, device-id, dp-cpu]

and use Jinja to create the content
    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ fnames | join(',') }} 
          {% for i in YML.response.result.response.result.entry %}
          {{ fnames | map('extract', i) | join(',') }}
          {% endfor %}

gives
  msg: |-
    hostname,device-id,dp-cpu
    FW1,1,4
    FW2,2,2

Write it to a file if this is what you want
    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/monitor-dev-health.csv
        content: |
          {{ fnames | join(',') }} 
          {% for i in YML.response.result.response.result.entry %}
          {{ fnames | map('extract', i) | join(',') }}
          {% endfor %}

gives
shell> cat /tmp/monitor-dev-health.csv 
hostname,device-id,dp-cpu 
FW1,1,4
FW2,2,2



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    YML:
      response:
        result:
          response:
            '@status': success
            result:
              entry:
              - cps: '26'
                deviating_fields:
                  dp-cpu: null
                  logging-rate: null
                device-id: '1'
                dp-cpu: '4'
                fan-total: '0'
                fan-up: '0'
                hostname: FW1
              - cps: '44'
                deviating_fields:
                  logging-rate: null
                device-id: '2'
                dp-cpu: '2'
                fan-total: '0'
                fan-up: '0'
                hostname: FW2

    fnames: [hostname, device-id, dp-cpu]

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: YML

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ fnames | join(',') }} 
          {% for i in YML.response.result.response.result.entry %}
          {{ fnames | map('extract', i) | join(',') }}
          {% endfor %}

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/monitor-dev-health.csv
        content: |
          {{ fnames | join(',') }} 
          {% for i in YML.response.result.response.result.entry %}
          {{ fnames | map('extract', i) | join(',') }}
          {% endfor %}


